# How can I increase the width of the black lines on an image with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image of a map with black borders, and I would like to make them thicker with opencv on python. To be honest, I am quite new to image processing and really don't know how this task can be accomplished. I already opened the image with just one color channel, since it is black and white, but I really have no idea as of what to do next to be able to accomplish what I need.

Here is the image that I am talking about:

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGE2b.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use morphology erode to make them thicker. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f